# Entity framework - Define connection where neither side is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have a problem, I have to create a model where we have two entities which CAN be linked together but can also exist as stand alone entities.

The model currently looks like this:

```
 public class Authorisation
 {
    public int AuthorisationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Change Change { get; set; }
}


public class Change
{
    public int ChangeID{ get; set; }

    public virtual Authorisation Authorisation { get; set; }

    public int? AuthorisationID{ get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this is that we can have an authorization record independent of a change, and some changes require authorisation and some dont, so neither side of the relationship is required.

I can configure this with the fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Authorisation>()
        .HasOptional(t => t.Change)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Authorisation);
```

And alls well, Except that the migration that it creates looks like this

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Changes",
            c => new
                {
                    ChangeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    AuthorisationID = c.Int(),
                    Authorisation_AuthorisationID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ChangeID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Authorisations", t => t.Authorisation_AuthorisationID)
            .Index(t => t.Authorisation_AuthorisationID);
```

EF is deciding that its going to add a new column (**Authorisation_AuthorisationID**) for me to use as the FK between the two entities, what I really want to be able to do is to use the change.AuthorisationID property as the FK onto the Authorisation, I cannot find a way to configure this at all (Please note that I need the FK to be in the model - for consistency with the rest of the app more than anything else).

To sum up I need to be able to create a relationship between two entities where both sides of the relationship are optional and if possible I want to be able to define the FK column myself.

Am I just approaching this wrong? Ive been staring at the same block of code for so long I could be missing something simple.

Comment: To clarify, After a bit of digging through the code and looking at what the app is actually putting into the database the issue that I have is actually more that I need to specify the FK myself, or at the very least be able to get at the automatically generated key from an instance of the entity

Answer (score 0):

Looks like explicit foreign key property is not supported for `one-to-one` relationships - there is no `HasForeignKey` Fluent API and also if you put `ForeignKey` attribute on the navigation property you get exception saying that multiplicity must be `*`.

So the only choice you have is to remove the explicit `Change.AuthorisationID` property and work only with navigation properties:

*Model:*

```
public class Authorisation
{
    public int AuthorisationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Change Change { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    public int ChangeID{ get; set; }
    public virtual Authorisation Authorisation { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Authorisation>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.Change)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Authorisation)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("AuthorisationID"));
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Bit of a pain, I could have done with being able to set the FK on the change object rather than having to retrieve the authorisation, but I guess if its the only option... Thanks!