# Use Fluent API Map method and define foreign key as a property in model together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

When i use the following codes, everything works well but i have not the foreign key property in my model to work with it in my logic classes:

**Content Model:**

```
public virtual File AudioFile{ get; set; }
```

**Fluent API:**

```
HasOptional(p => p.AudioFile)
           .WithOptionalDependent()
           .Map(x => x.MapKey("AudioFileId"));
```

---

**I want** define `AudioFileId` property in my model like this:

**Content Model:**

```
public int  AudioFileId{ get; set; }
public virtual File AudioFile{ get; set; }
```

When i use above *foreign key property* with *Fluent API Map method*, get this error:

> AudioFileId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'AudioFileId' is already defined.

**My question is:**

- How can i define  `AudioFileId` in `Model` class and use `Fluent API` to create this relation between `File` and `Content` Model?
- Is it possible?

Comment: Can you add the code of File and Content class ?

Comment: It's not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921447/entity-framework-define-connection-where-neither-side-is-required/39924310#39924310